# Unity 3D: Rear camera in device is behaving weird

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

Am working on taking snap from my device camera. The front camera is working good,but the rear camera is not upto the mark. It is showing upside down. I donno why it is behaving strange.[image]

Can anyone help me out.
Cheers!!

Comment: Mad selfie lol... As much as we'd love to be amazing mind readers we aren't... So you will need to post some code for help

Comment: That's why i have attached the screen shot,which can gives u idea about camera texture. @Savlon and if u want any specific code,i can give you

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to come up with a simple answer for your problem, this depends on wether you run it on iOS and Android. In general you need to adjust ( rotate and flip ) the resulting image based on the mirror and rotate value in the WebCamTexture.

There is a toolkit available that help you with solving some of these issues that you can take a look at. It's called Camera Capture Kit and is available on the assetstore ( https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/56673 ) - since the source is included for both iOS and Android it might be a good foundation for helping you tweak and solve your issue in your game or maybe it will just be a plug'n'play solution for your needs. It might let you save literally weeks in the long run since there is a lot of tweaking to get camera capturing right in Unity. Furthermore there is a functionality available to enable and disable flash light which might come in handy as well.

There is also a demo app included which is quite similar to what you have already been doing on your screens.

Cheers!